# Google Play Issue with Apps

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I'm pretty new to developing android apps. I have published my first 2 apps on Google Play and the issue is that I can't have them both installed at the same time. I had the first one on my phone, but when I wanted to install my second one I couldn't do it unless I uninstalled the first app.

Anyone had this issue before?

The only thing the apps have in common is probably the .jks key used to generate the .aab bundle, but that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Do they somehow have the exact same package name? This sounds exactly like what would happen if it were that.

Comment: No, they don't have the same package name.